# Is punctured $\mathbb{R}^n$ a CW complex?

Tags: general-topology

Is there an obvious/natural/simple CW complex structure for punctured Euclidean space, $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$?

EDIT: Here's what I've thought of. I can build $\mathbb{R}^n$ out of countably many cubes $e^n = [0,1]^n$ and attaching them along faces. Maybe I can build the interval $(0,1]$ as a CW complex by attaching infinitely many 1-cells $\{[1/(k+1),1/k]\}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$? I'm not sure if this is a CW complex. If it is, perhaps it can be generalized to higher dimensions.

Comment: What are your own thoughts about this?

Comment: Since Euclidean space is homeomorphic to the ball, you can not stress about countably many cubes, and just put a CW structure on the punctures ball. If you manage to do this, everything you could want out of a CW complex would be preserved by the homeomorphism between the two.

Comment: Are you saying that my guess can be generalized to higher dimensions? Would either of you mind posting a fleshed out answer?

Comment: OK, good job on $R^N$. Do you know that $R^n -\{0\}$ is homeomorphic to $R\times S^{n-1}$? Can you give $S^k$ a structure of a CW complex?

Comment: Yes I know how to put a CW complex structure on the $n$-sphere. Is there a CW complex structure for the punctured plane that has finitely many cells?

Comment: Any CW complex with finitely many chains would have to be compact (the image of a compact space under a continuous map is compact).

Comment: @MoisheCohen As a consequence of your statement, punctured Euclidean space cannot be written as a CW complex with finitely many cells? I'm not familiar with the the meaning of a "chain."

Comment: Sorry, I meant "cells", not "chains". Other than that, yes, you need infinitely many cells once your space is noncompact.